# How to split array values using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to split array values using 'angularjs.split' method? It is not working here:

```js
var items =["Regular Servicing & Maintenance","Faults (Interior & Exterior)"];
console.log(items.split(',');
```

Comment: is your giving an error ? because there's a space in "console.log(items .split(','); "

Comment: What do you have to do? Split is for strings to be splitted in array but you have an array, so what do you want? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: What is the desired result that you want to achieve?

Comment: i need to split  Regular Servicing & Maintenance and Faults (Interior & Exterior)

Comment: @sreemohan That is still unclear. Please update your answer to include the desired output.

Comment: i need to split items and filter based on item values .here i have selected Regular Servicing & Maintenance ,Faults (Interior & Exterior) .i need to check separately Regular Servicing & Maintenance and Faults (Interior & Exterior) where ever matches in services

Comment: You can simply access Regular Servicing & Maintenance as items[0] and Faults (Interior & Exterior) as items[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question is confusing on a number of levels. For one, there isn't an AngularJS function that I'm seeing in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) for split.

There's a JavaScript method called [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), but it's used to split a string into an array of substrings, per the linked documentation.

For another, you're already instantiating the items variable with an array of strings though, so you're not really going to get anything from that that you don't already have in the initial value.

## Split Method

Now, if you had a string like the following example, you could split that by the commas and yield an array similar to what you've got in your question:

```
var str = "Apples, Bananas, Cherries";
var arr = str.split(', '); //Note the space as well
console.log(arr); //Yields ["Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries"]
```

## Join Method

But if you're looking for the inverse and you're rather looking to join these into a comma-separated string, you might look at the [join()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) JavaScript method that would look like the following (continued from above):

```
var result = arr.join(', '); //Note the space again
console.log(result); //Apples, Bananas, Cherries
```

## IndexOf Method

To match the comment you left after I posted this though, if you're looking for the index value of the array that matches a given string, look at the [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) method, per the following (again, building from the above example):

var index = arr.indexOf('Bananas'); //Yields 1
var indexRes = arr[index]; //Yields 'Bananas'

If you're looking for something else, you're going to need to clarify the original question.

Comment: var services = Regular Servicing & Maintenance,Faults (Interior & Exterior;

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. That's going to fail because you have invalid and undefined objects on either side of the string (in the middle where you dropped the quotes). If you mean to present all of that as one string, please look above at the Split Method section.

Answer (score 0):

The below code represents JavaScript code

```
var items = ["Regular Servicing & Maintenance", "Faults (Interior & Exterior)"];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log("Input:-" + items[i])
        console.log("Output:-" + items[i].split('&'));
    }
```

```
Input: -Regular Servicing & Maintenance
Output: -Regular Servicing, Maintenance
Input: -Faults(Interior & Exterior)
Output: -Faults(Interior, Exterior)
```

How to split array values using angularJs

```
$scope.items = [{
        'item': 'Regular Servicing & Maintenance'
    }, {
        'item': 'Faults (Interior & Exterior)'
    }]
    $scope.array = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value, key) {
        var splitLength = value.item.split('&').length;
        for (var i = 0; i < splitLength; i++) {
            $scope.array.push(value.item.split('&')[i]);
        }
    });
    console.log($scope.array)
```